# ShareActionProvider set a different text for Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, shareactionprovider

I try to use ShareActionProvider. It's work but i want put a different text when the user click on Twitter.

How can i fix it?

This my code, the object News contents a title and a url

```
When he clicks on Twitter :

    @account_name myText

And for other

    myText

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_news, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
    shareActionProvider
            .setShareHistoryFileName(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    return true;
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {

        // Here, is Twitter, add "@Televesdre" in the message
    News news = detailAdapter.getCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    String message = news.getTitle() + "\n\n Article: " + news.getUrl();

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

I search how to do before coding because i haven't no idea how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html)